# How to schedule a command only once without 'at' and using 'crontab'

Tags: ubuntu, scheduled-tasks

I would like to run a command (simulation) after 6 hours only once.

I came across "**at**" to do my job but unfortunately I have no rights to install the package.

I also came across "**crontab**" which takes time and date as parameters.

In my case, I would just like to run the simulation command once after 6 hours. Is this possible using crontab or am I being too ambitious?

Appreciate if you hint me at any other alternative.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/1002227/alternative-batch-command-for-resources-rather-than-load/1002233#1002233 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a shell script that sleeps for 6 hours, then executes your command.  Run it "now" and your command will execute once, six hours later.

```
#!/bin/bash

sleep 6h  # or, "sleep 21600" if your system doesn't support the "6h" syntax
yourcmd
```